# Android retrofit content type image/jpg

Tags: android, retrofit

I got such a problem, i have to upload an image using Content-Type `image/jpeg`  ,but i says in logs `formdata/multipart`. Is there any configuration ?

```
@Multipart
@POST("/Users/uploadAvatar")
void upload(@Query("id") String id,
            @Part("file") TypedFile file,
            Callback<User> cb);
```

**Class**

```
 TrackerService service = ServiceGenerator.createService(TrackerService.class);
            TypedFile typedFile = new TypedFile("image/jpeg", file);

            service.upload("56d831c7dde67d9e255526d0",typedFile,  new Callback<User>() {

                @Override
                public void success(User user, Response response) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Success Uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }

                @Override
                public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Fail", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are using Retrofit library 1.9
I suggest you to use RestAdapter instead of TrackerService.See, Example below

```
    RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder().setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL).setEndpoint(API).build();

    TypedFile typedFile = new TypedFile("*/*", new File(resultPath));
    upload_file hit_Api = restAdapter.create(upload_file.class);

    hit_Api.uploadFile(typedFile,new callback<String>() {
                @Override
                public void success(String s, Response response) {


                }

                @Override
                public void failure(RetrofitError error) {

                }
            });
```

upload_file is my interface class edit it according to your case.